# Insurance covering claims of patent infringement: has anyone here direct experience?

Tags: infringement

I found a few insurance companies which seem to offer some cover for claims of patent infringement. Here is how they are briefly advertised:

"Patent infringement liability insurance is professional liability insurance for manufacturers, users and sellers who are accused of infringing a patent holder’s rights."

I have read somewhere else that annual premiums for this kind of insurance are in the 1000$-25000$ range.

Has any of you ever bought an insurance of such kind? what is your experience?

Answer (score 1):

Talk with a patent attorney before you even consider insurance like this. More likely than not, it's completely unnecessary and a waste of important capital that could be used in better places.

If infringement is a legitimate and real concern there are likely better (and cheaper) ways to handle it than getting insurance. For example, work with a patent attorney on a design-around or get a non-infringement opinion or invalidity opinion for the specific patent(s) in question.